# Understanding Unique Value Symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I'm trying to display different soil types with unique values. For some reason all but one soil type shows up when I choose add all values in the unique values symbology window. The soil type has it's own attribute and information. I really don't understand why only one is not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Arcmap 10.4

Comment: Can you show what the specific Value (eg. 'Clay', 'Loam') and Type (eg. Text, Short) were for the value that didn't populate with "Add All Values"?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, my answer is yes. Instead of having its own symbology and label it ends up getting grouped under "all other values".

Comment: Could you please post some screenshots of the Attribute Table and Symbology Window?

Comment: Look closely in the attribute table for the one soil type that is not showing up and see if there is anything different about it that could be throwing off the Symbology tab. Sounds like the data to me.